# Refresh problems with data from pojos in JAVA

Tags: jpa, pojo

I'm working with Oracle DB and Primefaces. I created the POJO's with Netbeans IDE and I'm facing the following issue: I have a class with many child classes, with each class having its own screen. For example, I have a class Dad and a class Children.

I can insert or update Dad in a specific screen and there's other screen where I can list all Dads and delete them or just redirect to a list of all the related children

With childrens it's almost the same - I can insert update children for a specific Dad in a different screen and there's another screen where I can delete a specific child for a specific Dad.

If I have only 1 child related to a Dad table when I delete this child and list my dad table from DB in the association of the class Dad, I still see this child even if it doesn't exist in my DB. If I stop debugging and restart the program, when I list Dad it doesn't show the deleted child anymore (which is the expected behavior).

I think that maybe there is some kind of cache from the session but I'm having trouble finding the issue.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OPM_ESPECIFICACION_IMPRES"
,schema="ORDENES_PRODUCCION"
, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"ORDEN",     "ID_TIPO_IMPRESO"}) 
)

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="opmEspecificacionImpres")
public Set<OpmValorEspecificacion> getOpmValorEspecificacions() {
    return this.opmValorEspecificacions;
}

public void setOpmValorEspecificacions(Set<OpmValorEspecificacion> opmValorEspecificacions) {
    this.opmValorEspecificacions = opmValorEspecificacions;
}
```

This is an extract from one of my POJO's class

Comment: Can you please do two things for me? (1) Break your question into paragraphs, and (2) make it clear what your question is.

Comment: (3) make clear why this is a PrimeFaces problem (tags are for where the problem is, not what you use), (4) read [ask] and [mcve] and improve the question. (5) use correct tags (e.g. JPA, Hibernate etc)